# Package Installer on Samsung crashes when updating my app

Tags: android, crash, samsung, packageinstaller

I have had this app for years on Play Store.

Now I have the latest update ready but... my Samsung A52 started to behave oddly: when I try to install the new version, it silently stops the update. On other Android phones everything is OK as always.
I catch an error on my Samsung only when logging with my PC; the **Package Installer** appears to crash:

```
Process: com.google.android.packageinstaller,  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver 
com.android.packageinstaller.InstallEventReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Maybe it started with the latest update to the phone's software (Android 14 UI 6.0)
So, now, I'm reluctant to upload the new version on the Play Store: what if all Samsung mobiles do the same?

I tried to look for similar experiences on the web but I just found one single thread on Reddit.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem, while updating an app installed originally via the Play Store, using an APK (but with the same signature). If I uninstall the running app first, the APK install works fine.